# What happens to the Real and Reactive power when I increase the excitation current in a 3-Phase Synchronous Generator?

Tags: ac, three-phase, electric-machine, power-generation, synchronous-motor

Basically my doubt is, for the same load, why does the Real power remain constant when I increase the excitation current?

Comment: What are your assumptions for changes in load and RPM or ?

Comment: There is no change in load

Comment: what changes then. dont assume

Comment: The only thing that changes is the excitation current, and by increasing it the emf increases. since it is synchronous the rpms is always 120*f/p

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the excitation current under conditions where the armature terminal voltage increases but the load current and the real power do not change, the power factor must decrease because power = V X A X pf. That explains why it is possible. To explain why the power and current remained constant with increasing voltage, you must know more about the load or the distribution system that is acting as a load.